# Renaming file with portion of parent's directory name

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have many directories named `201801XX_samename_stillsame` where `XX` changes and the rest stay the same. Within are files that all have the same name, e.g. `filename.png`. I would need a `bash` script to change the `filename.png` according to the variable portion of the directory's name, e.g.

```
for file in **_samename_stillsame/; do
    #extract portion of the name as e.g., $date
    cp filename.png "$date".png
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for dir in 201801*_samename_stillsame/; do
    cp "$dir/filename.png" "${dir:7:2}.png"
done
```

for each directory copy the file. The `${dir:7:2}` is a substring of the variable, 2 characters from the 7th character (ie. the 'XX' part).

Comment: I chose yours because it was the easiest to "read". Tried and it worked at the first try. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
for d in $(ls -d 2018*_samename_stillsame); do 
  mv $d/{filename,$(echo "$d" | cut -d '_' -f1)}.png; 
done
```

EDIT: Based on @kamil-cuk answer and because I didn't realise you just wanted the 
        XX part

```
for d in $(ls -d 2018*_samename_stillsame); do 
  mv $d/{filename,${d:6:2}}.png; 
done
```

*In my case when testing the index actually start at 0 not 1 so to have the seventh character you need to slice at 6*

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
shopt -s nullglob
kn='_samename_stillsame/'

for f in **"$kn"; do
   mv -- "$f/filename.png" "$f${f%%$kn}.png"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Find all directory names, use `sed` to construct a `mv` command and the `e` option to execute the constructed command.

```
find 201801* -maxdepth 1 -type d | 
   sed -r 's#201801(..)_samename_stillsame#mv &/filename.png &/\1.png#e'
```

Comment: Do you mean the `e` on the side of the `#`? If so, what does the `s#` do? Is `s` for `string`?

Comment: In `sed 's/old/new/' the `s` stands for substitute. When a string old/new has a slash, you can escape it or use another character. I used the `#`. When you remove the last `e` of the command, you see what strings will be made. The `e` will execute the constructed commands.